# How can I show all information in a table and count how many times its shown up in another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working in SQLite3 where I am trying to use a SELECT statement to show the entire detail of a table and then count how many times it's appeared in another table.

For example: I have 2 tables, A_ID being a foreign key to A and ID being the primary key for Table A

Table A : ID | Name -> info `(1,Sam), (2, Michael), (3,Gordon)`

Table B : A_ID | Task -> info `(1, T1), (1, T2), (2, T3), (3, T4)`

OUTPUT: ID | NAME | COUNT() -> info `(1 | Sam | 2), (2 | Michael | 1), (3 | Gordon | 1)`

I had thought to try

```
SELECT \*, COUNT(*)
FROM A
WHERE ID = (SELECT A_ID FROM B);
```

But this statement only showed me the first item and not the rest.
Sorry about the formatting, I'm not too familiar with using this yet. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause to get the values for *each* person in `A`, and `LEFT JOIN` table `A` to `B` on `A_ID` to get the counts of tasks for each person:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, COUNT(B.Task) AS Tasks
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Name
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
ID  Name        Tasks
1   Sam         2
2   Michael     1
3   Gordon      1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j1Weste6yCUm5w9uzVSwrX/0)

Comment: Thank you, I went with your idea, I had thought of using a natural join at the beginning, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You can't use a natural join in this case because the column name you are joining on is not the same in both tables. You could use an inner join, but that would give you no rows for  people who had no tasks. Using a left join allows you to return rows for them as well (of course, if you don't want that behaviour, revert to an inner join)

Answer (score 0):

You should use GROUP BY statement with aggregating functions:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(task)
FROM A left join B on A.ID=B.A_ID
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left` join of `TableA` to `TableB` and `group by` id and name:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(b.a_id) counter
from TableA a left join TableB b
on b.a_id = a.id
group by a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, I recommend a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.A_ID = A.ID)
FROM A;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `B(A_ID)` and avoids the outer aggregation.